# CakePHP Validation error not displaying for primary key that is not 'id'

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a model which has a primary key of 'staff_code'

I have customer validation rules as below:

```
public $validate = array(
        'staff_code' => array(
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'This Staff Code already exists',
                'last' => true
            ),
            'sc_required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'The Staff Code must be specified',
        ))

    );
```

When the field is not unique the validation error does not display

Has anyone overcome this error, I think it is related to the primary key being inputted by the user.

I have to keep the schema as it is as it is used by another piece of software and would be a real nightmare to change the way this works.

Not sure if need but my view is :

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Staff');
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'staff_code' => array('type' => 'text', 'autocomplete' => 'off'),
    'login_name' => array('type' => 'text', 'autocomplete' => 'off'),
    'person_name' => array('type' => 'text', 'autocomplete' => 'off'),
    'password',
    '_allowed_to_do_po',
    'is_active'
));
echo $this->Form->input('role', array('options' =>
    array('user' => 'user', 'admin' => 'admin'), 'empty' => false, 'default'=>'user'));
echo $this->Form->end(array(
    'label' => 'Save',
    'class' => 'btn'
));
?>
```

...and my custom save function from the Staff controller:

```
function emSave($data) {
    if (!$this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('staff_code' => $data['Staff']['staff_code'])))) {
        if ($this->save($data)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

NB: The error messages work fine for my other fields that are no primary keys.

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using? What is the custom save function used for? Are you using MySQL, PostgreSQL, or something else? What type of field is `staff_code`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, I think, that you are doing a validation lookup in your controller before you are calling save. Save automatically calls your validation, so you don't need to look it up first, that's the whole point of the Unique rule, it does that for you.

You might also want to add `'required' => true` to your validation if you want the field to be valid.

However, having a user input a primary key field in your database is bad practice in my opinion. It should be automatically generated and invisible to the user.